# Any one liner code to find all info about libcurl support on a server?

Tags: libcurl

Is there an equivalent to phpinfo() for libcurl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest I think is:

```
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
```

and then use some regular expressions to extract curl info. Several examples can be found in the comments here http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: Thank you. Made a small mod to getModuleSetting I found in the link you mentioned and now I do have my one liner.